# Python- regular expressions - filter between multi-line text

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to filter 'abc', 'def\nghj', 'klm' from the following line separated text file.

```
********
abc
********
def
ghj
********
klm
```

I've tried to escape `'\*'` character and group the rest (with an expression like `'.*?\*(.*)*.*'`), but no luck.

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance..

Comment: Why not just iterate through the file and grab every other line?

Comment: I know I can do this, but I would like to learn how to do it with regex (unless someone tells me it's not worth it:) )

Comment: it's not worth it but `re.split("\*+",s)` will do what you want

Comment: Thanks a ton! The reason why it's not worth it, is it because it simply needs to go all the lines but perform any filtering inside the lines?@PadraicCunningham

Comment: regex can be slow, and if you read a huge file in one go in hopes of matching it against a regex, well, your system will start to complain at you. Sure it would work fine if the file is reasonably small, but we have no idea what kind of file you're working with. The other alternative would be to read the file line by line which would make it easier to handle, but then, you won't be able to use regex... So, read line by line and switch 'modes' when you encounter `*`s.

Comment: But, there is a flip side to reading/parsing every single line. The i/o overhead is very large, especially if 1/4 of the file is CRLF's. I'd stick to reading the whole file. 16 gigs of ram at $150 bucks, and file paging, pretty much makes this a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

Could use something like below *in MULTI-LINE MODE*
where `[*]{4}` represents the delimiter.

```
 # (?:^(?![*]{4}).*(?:\r?\n|$))+

 (?:
      ^ 
      (?! [*]{4} )
      .* 
      (?: \r? \n | $ )
 )+
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 10 , len 5 ) 
abc
--------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 25 , len 10 ) 
def
ghj
---------------------

 **  Grp 0 -  ( pos 45 , len 3 ) 
klm
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look for block of text which doesn't contain asterisk symbol, you can use `re.findall` and multiline mode:

```
text = '''********
abc
********
def
ghj
********
klm
'''
re.findall(r'^[^*]+$', text, re.M)
```

Or, if you want to find block of text splitted by line of asterisks, you should use `re.split`:

```
re.split(r'(?:^|\n)\*+(?:\n|$)', text, re.M)
```